# Битовые операции в Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Есть массив байтов

```
var bytes = [10,20,30,40,20,20]
```

необходимо получить данные начиная с третьего бита второго байта, взять 16 бит и на основе полученных данных создать новый массив байтов.

Как это можно сделать?

В Swift тяжко:(.. 
На Java я сделал так:

```
int startByte = 1;
int startBit = 2
int countBit = 16;

byte[] array = new byte[]{10,20,30,40,20,20};

int size = (int) Math.ceil((startBit + countBit) / 8d);
BitSet result = getBitSet(array, startByte, startBit, countBit);

byte[] newArray= Arrays.copyOf(result.toByteArray(), size); //новый массив на основе полученных битов 

 public static BitSet getBitSet(byte[] array, int fromByteIndex, int fromByteBitIndex, int bitsCount) {
        BitSet arrayBitSet = BitSet.valueOf(array);
        int fromIndex = fromByteIndex * 8 + fromByteBitIndex;
        return arrayBitSet.get(fromIndex, fromIndex + bitsCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш вопрос заинтересовал меня и я набросал свое решение, которое включает подходы, что я видел ранее на англоязычном stackoverflow.

Массив байтов задается следующим образом:

```
typealias Byte = UInt8
let bytes: [Byte] = [0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x20, 0x20]
```

если сделать `print(bytes)` то выведет `[16, 32, 48, 64, 32, 32]`.

Для бит создадим перечисление:

```
enum Bit: UInt8, CustomStringConvertible {
    case zero, one

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return "1"
        case .zero:
            return "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Для преобразования `Bytes` в `Bits` будем добавим следующее расширение:

```
extension Byte {
    var bits: [Bit] {
        let bitsInByte = 8
        var bitsArray = [Bit](repeating: Bit.zero, count: bitsInByte)
        for (index, _) in bitsArray.enumerated() {
            let bitVal: UInt8 = 1 << UInt8(bitsInByte - 1 - index)
            let check = self & bitVal
            if check != 0 {
                bitsArray[index] = Bit.one
            }
        }
        return bitsArray
    }
}
```

Биты будем складывать в следующий массив:

```
var bitResult: [Bit] = []
```

Добавлю ваши стартовые параметры:

```
var startByte = 1 //с какого Byte
let startBit = 2 //с какого Bit
var countBit = 16 //сколько Bit
```

Сначала я вычисляю первый кусок данных:

```
for i in startBit..<(countBit > 8 ? 8 : countBit) {//8 - это количество Bit в Byte
    bitResult.append(bytes[startByte].bits[I])
    //использую этот счетчик для того, чтобы следить, сколько bit осталось добавить
    countBit -= 1
}
```

Теперь основное тело:

```
while countBit / 8 > 0 {
    startByte += 1
    for i in 0..<8 {
        bitResult.append(bytes[startByte].bits[i])
        countBit -= 1
    }
}
```

И последний кусок:

```
startByte += 1
for i in 0..<countBit {
    bitResult.append(bytes[startByte].bits[i])
    countBit -= 1
}
```

Выведем текущий результат в консоль:

```
print(bitResult)
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Нам осталось преобразовать битовый массив обратно в байты.
Будем использовать для этого следующий метод:

```
func bitsToBytes(bits: [Bit]) -> [UInt8] {
    let numBytes = 1 + (bits.count - 1) / 8
    var bytes = [Byte](repeating: 0, count: numBytes)

    for (index, bit) in bits.enumerated() {
        if bit == .one {
            bytes[index / 8] += Byte(1 << (7 - index % 8))
        }
    }
    return bytes
}
```

Финальный результат получаем следующий образом:

```
let resultBytesArray = bitsToBytes(bits: bitResult)
print(resultBytesArray)
[128, 193]
```

Я не гарантирую оптимального результата. Вы можете доработать мой подход. Но я проверил с вашими данными, и сделал несколько тестов, все они были успешны. Если `countBit % 8 != 0`, то недостающие биты в итоговом результате будут нули.
Если есть ошибки - дайте знать, я постараюсь доработать.

Comment: Попробовал, данные на Java и на Swift совпадают! Пока все отлично! Спасибо, выручил!!

Comment: Возникла проблема, когда необходимо получить не ровно 16 bit, а например 14 bit.. т.е. мы берём со 2го бита 1го байта 14бит и по идеи должны из полученных 14 бит получить 2 байта. 14/8 и округляем в большую сторону.

Comment: @DuosDuo изменил ответ, и теперь он учитывает и такие случаи. Просто дополняем нулями оставшиеся биты.

Comment: Работает безупречно!) Спасибо